# Broken recovery on Huawei Mate SE

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, huawei, lineageos

So a while back I was trying to flash an unofficial TWRP recovery, and I ran into a bit of an issue. The process involved fastboot flashing a recovery partition that is unique to Huawei phones (something like recovery_ramdisk). Anyways, I essentially flashed an incomplete recovery that gets stuck in a boot loop whenever it tries to boot. To further complicate things, the phone will always try to boot to recovery after forcing it to power off. It always boots to this broken recovery regardless of other button combos or ADB commands (i.e. I can't get into download mode). The only way it boots to the system is when the battery drains to zero. It's as if a flag is reset when the phone drains to zero. It remembers to boot to recovery if I try to restart however.

My question is, is there a way to repair the recovery? Why does it forget to boot to recovery after it's battery expires, but then remembers after it powers on? Can I somehow get it into download mode? It's also running lineage 14 which I guess I flashed properly before TWRP.

Comment: on zero battery keep holding Volume Down and connect charger, that should bring you fastboot mode